# Reflection of WCF's deserialized JSON Classes

Tags: c#, .net, json, wcf, reflection

I have run in an interesting issue...

Imagine simple class hiearchy like this:

```
class ClassA
{
    public ClassB RefClassB { get; set; }

    public ClassA()
    {
        RefClassB = new ClassB();
    }
}

class ClassB
{
    public ClassC RefClassC { get; set; }

    public ClassB()
    {
        RefClassC = new ClassC();
    }
}

class ClassC
{
    public int IntProperty { get; set; }
}
```

..and this code which iterates through the above hiearchy using `.NET Reflection`

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ClassA instanceOfClassA = new ClassA();
    GetProperties(c);
}

private void GetProperties<T>(T instance)
{
    GetProperties(typeof(T), instance);
}

private void GetProperties(Type classType, object instance)
{
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
    {
        object val = property.GetValue(instance, null);
        if (val == null)
        {
            // e.g. I put to text box property names
            textBox1.Text += property.Name + Environment.NewLine;
        }
        else
        {
            GetProperties(property.PropertyType, val);
        }
    }
}
```

**this works great** if use the code in for example WinForms Application.

But the problem is, that I need to use this inside my WCF Ajax Service to loop through incoming JSON parameter, like this:

```
namespace AeviGateway.Service
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        MyModel.JSONResponse MyMethod(MyModel.JSONRequest data);
    }

    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
    [ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
    public class Service: IService
    {

        public MyModel.JSONResponse MyMethod(MyModel.JSONRequest data)
        {
            GetProperties(data); // Here is the problem - it seems like all subclasses would be null..
            ....
        }
    }
}
```

JSON is like this:

```
{
    "header": {
        "version": "1",
        "token": "d1c2c5b4-c5c6-4a31-89a5-75d4db4acaae"
    },
    "request": {
        "number": 10,
        "SubObject": {
            "UID": "320f324e-22cd-4bd3-9e58-d965749d1986",
            "Number": 11,
            "Text": "something"
        }
    }
}
```

..is called from JavaScript AJAX. Of course, the `MyModel.JSONRequest` is defined exactly to reflect the JSON object. The problem is - the method to iterate through hiearchy doesn't work. It doesn't step into sub classes..which is strange because the same code works in my testing WinForms application.

EDIT: 
Here is the class definition for JSONRequest

```
public class SubObjectClass
{
    public string UID {get; set;}
    public int Number {get; set;}
    public string Text {get; set;}
}

public class JSONRequest
{
    public class RequestClass
    {
        public int number { get; set; }
        public SubObjectClass SubObject {get; set}
    }

    public class RequestHeader
    {
        public int version { get; set; }
        public string token {get; set}
    }

    public RequestHeader header { get; set; }
    public RequestClass request { get; set; }
}
```

Any help, comment, tip, idea...would be appreciated. Thank you

### SOLVED

Just if anyone would have similar issue. There were 2 things:

1.When recursively iterating through the Classes hiearchy I had to use this line to check whether the property is an instance of class and I should step into or not (since String is also a class which I don't want to step into)

```
if ((value != null) && 
    (property.PropertyType.Module.ScopeName != "CommonLanguageRuntimeLibrary"))
{
    GetProperties(property.PropertyType, value);
}
```

2.My solutions consists of 2 projects. The "GetProperties" was inside the second project which was referenced in the first project (the WCF service project). When I put the "GetReflection" code directly inside the WCF project it works.

Comment: I know you wrote, "Of course, the `MyModel.JSONRequest` is defined exactly to reflect the JSON object", but can you show it to us anyway?

Comment: @dbc Thank you. Will do so tomorrow as I'm out of the office. The Model class is decorated by [DataContract] and its members by [DataMember].

Comment: I just tried your code `GetProperties(instanceOfClassA)` -- and it doesn't print anything.  That's because you only print information for null properties, and in that case, only the name.   For your JSON class, `GetProperties()` throws an exception because you need to skip indexed properties, i.e. those for which `property.GetIndexParameters().Length > 0` - for instance [`string` has an indexed property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.chars%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @dbc thanks for the point. strangely it works on win forms app. However, I noticed in my WCF service inside the "GetProperties" method that "classType" doesn't hold any properties. When I do "classType.ToString()" it just says "System.Object" which doesn't contain class type information I suppose...and "foreach (PropertyInfo property in classType.GetProperties(BindingFlags...." contains 0 elements. It doesn't do anything. Not really sure where the catch is. Anyway, feel free to make your comment as answer and I'm gonna give it at least point for your time and good hint. Thanks dbc